# Remove the last element each list of list in Python 3

Tags: python, list, nested

I would like to know how I can remove the last element of each list, which is stored in a list. I have this example:

```
a=[ [1, 2, 3, 4, ''], [ 4, 5, 6, 7, ''], [ 8, 8, 8, 8, '']]
```

And I want to remove the last element of each list:

```
a_removed=[[1, 2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

I have tried to use a map function and filter function, but they only work in a single list, not in a list of list.

Any ideas on this?

Thank you

Comment: Please share what you tried?

Comment: `for x in a: x.pop(0)` if you want to operate directly on `a`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, ''], [4, 5, 6, 7, ''], [8, 8, 8, 8, '']]
>>> a_removed = [x[:-1] for x in a]
>>> a_removed
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]]
>>>
```